# How to replace & with &amp; in Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, confluence-rest-api

I am sending Json to a confluence page but receive a BadRequest error. I have tested extensively and been able to send Json using the same code. The only difference between the json that will not send is that it contains an ampersand `&`. The Json that will send has escaped the ampersand `&amp;`.

```
   jsonHolder = {
        "id": "....",
        "type": "page"......

        "body": {
            "storage": {
                "value": "<table><tbody><tr><td>Row1</td><td>Row2</td><td>Row3</td><td>Empty Sour & Tar</td></tr></tbody></table>",
            },
    }
```

This is only a sample of a much larger set and if possable I would only escape `&` as when I escape the overall json, formatting becomes an issue.
The json is being put into `Net::HTTP::Put.new(uri)` body.

```
p jsonHolder = JSON.generate(jsonResult)

request.body = jsonHolder
```

I have been trying to find a similar examples but many seem to be working on strings, but when I `.to_s`, the json is parsed and not correct.

Comment: `&` is not valid in HTML. It is not the JSON that needs to encode the `&` to `&amp;`, your HTML fragment is just not valid HTML in the first place. Fix it at the source not when generating JSON. Where does that fragment come from, how is it generated?

Comment: jsonResult is being created from a merger of a hashmap and array.

` row.each do |column|
         htmlTable.to_s.concat("<th>")
         htmlTable.to_s.concat(column.to_s)
  htmlTable.to_s.concat("</th>")
 end`

I have tried using `htmlTable.to_s.concat(URI.escape(column.to_s))` but this will only remove spacing @spickermann

Comment: Any reason we can't do something simple like `jsonHolder.gsub!(/&(?!amp;)/,'&amp;')`

Comment: @RossODalaigh this line `jsonHolder = JSON.generate(jsonResult)` makes it a `String`. But for the `Hash` you could use `JSON.parse(jsonHolder.to_json.gsub(/&(?!amp;)/,'&amp;'))` which will result in a `Hash` with the `&` replaced with `&amp;`

Comment: Oh hey that solved it!!! Thank a million @engineersmnky any perticular reason why I gettting an error saying there is no implicit method for `gsub` on a hashmap when i had `jsonHolder.gsub('&','&amp;')`

Comment: Because `Hash` does not have a `gsub` method but `json` is just a `String` and `JSON.parse` makes a json String into a ruby Object in this case a `Hash`

Comment: Okay, you would not believe how long this has taken, I just started learning Ruby last week, thanks @engineersmnky :)

Comment: No problem glad it worked out and welcome to ruby where the help is helpful and the documentation is explicit